# Bootstrap carousel - Adjusting Overflow hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a fullscreen carousel with lots of text in it. When i make the display smaller, the carousel-caption simply stays hidden and I can not scroll down.

When I delete the overflow hidden property, I get an ugly scrollbar at the bottom of the page whenever the slide changes.

Comment: How do we know you're not lying?

Comment: With hidden overflow: http://i.imgur.com/xL0NP5r.png and without hidden overflow: http://i.imgur.com/Q5Ul2Fv.png. I am trying to make a code snippet with bootply but it doesnt like my code :(

Comment: You have two options: 1. reduce the vertical space between the elements; 2. make overflow-x: hidden; and overflow-y: auto;

Comment: Oh man I didnt even know there is a seperate overflow attribute for x and y... Thank you. You saved me tons of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the vertical scroll by setting:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Remove the horizontal scroll by setting:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Read more about `overflow` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).